# get apex package prefix name?

Tags: apex-code, soql

is there a way to get the prefix name of a managed package in apex?

I have a SOSL query but the app is in a developer org and in a managed package, if I have a way to get the package name, it would be great, because I don't have to hard code it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your code part of the package? If so, you don't need to use the prefix. Otherwise, if it's for an object then surely you're dependant on that package being installed, and as such, hard coding the name wouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this, AFAIK, is to use the Metadata API. You can call [describeMetadata()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_describe.htm) and then evaluate the organizationNamespace (String) value returned in [describeMetadataResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_describemeta_result.htm).

From *within* Apex you could do a less elegant try/catch approach with dynamic SOQL/DML, at least to determine if something you *suspect* is there is actually there. Though this won't tell you what namespace prefix actually IS there like the Metadata API will.

Lacey is correct that you don't need the prefix, though name ambiguity can become a problem. So for example, if you have a custom object `Expense__c` and have installed an accounting package which includes `ACCT__Expense__c`, you definitely want to explicitly include the `ACCT__` prefix if intending to access the managed package object as opposed to your own.

Answer (score 1):

The UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('nsPrefix') will throw a TypeException if the namespace passed in is not a valid namespace of an installed package (or managed package you're developing). I think this is the closest you're going to get without the metadata API.